# Issues about importing data through HDF5

Tags: hdf5, dolphindb

when importing through HDF5 interface, loading plug-in is failed
The script used is as follows:

```py
loadPlugin("plugins/hdf5/PluginHdf5.txt")
```

The prompt is: Can't find module

Answer (score 0):

On windows, the imported plug-ins needs to be specified with full path. You can use the following scripts for loading:

```py
loadPlugin(getHomeDir()+"/plugins/hdf5/PluginHDF5.txt")
```

Besides, loadPlugin needs to be executed independently.
For the commonly used plug-ins, it is recommended to pre-load them by adding configuration item "preloadModules".

```py
preloadModules=plugins::mysql,plugins::mqtt
```

In this way you can use them directly after the node is started.